# UISearchController + UICollectionView error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I'm building an app that uses UICollectionView to display content. I added the UISearchController to section header and everything works just fine. However when I dismiss the search and than edit the first item (row 0, section 0) I got this error:

> 2014-08-19 18:18:37.415 Slick[28793:1772932] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[SLCollectionView _updateWithItems:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3232.3/UICollectionView.m:4343 2014-08-19
>   18:18:37.416 Slick[28793:1772932] CoreData: error: Serious application
>   error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of
>   NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Attempt to delete item containing first responder that refused to resign with userInfo (null)

When I edit any other item first than everything is OK. The confusing thing is that I'm not even deleting the first item, just editing it. Do you guys have any idea what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in simulator. On real device it works as it should.